# алгоритм пространственной фильтрации

Tags: python, matlab, обработка-изображений

Как реализовать алгоритм пространственной фильтрации для нахождения объекта на однородном фоне? Язык Python (OpenCV и NumPy) или Matlab

Comment: Что именно вы хотите получить? Найти контур объекта на однородном фоне или что-то другое? Вы хотите реализовать алгоритм самостоятельно или воспользоваться готовыми функциями OpenCV?

Comment: хочу найти контур объекта, ну и в последующих кадрах следить за объектом. Можно воспользоваться готовыми функциями, от них уже можно понять как все работает и если что, реализовать самостоятельно

Comment: вы можете выложить пример изображения?

Comment: https://pp.userapi.com/c840722/v840722323/27db8/EgA3jVxSaNc.jpg
https://static9.depositphotos.com/1000627/1085/i/950/depositphotos_10855102-stock-photo-plane-flying-on-the-sky.jpg